# How do I find the path of current Ipython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

As simple as it sounds, how do I get the save path (location of the .ipynb file) from a cell within the notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out one can use some javascript magic to get the notebook path from some  attributes in the HTML body of the notebook page:

```
%%javascript 
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel; 
var proj = window.document.body.getAttribute('data-project'); 
var path = window.document.body.getAttribute('data-notebook-path'); 
var command = "proj = " + "'"+proj+"'";
kernel.execute(command);
var command = "path = " + "'"+path+"'" kernel.execute(command)
```

After executing the above in a cell one can get the path by doing

```
import os 
os.path.join( proj, path)
```

Comment: This didn't work in IPython 3.2.0, Python 3.4: `Javascript error adding output!`
`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
`See your browser Javascript console for more details.`

Comment: I partially solved that issue by replacing IPython with Jupyter, but the solution is still not complete, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

With Jupyter you can get the **relative** path of the notebook in the URL with:

```
%%javascript 
var kernel = Jupyter.notebook.kernel; 
var command = ["notebookPath = ",
               "'", window.document.body.dataset.notebookPath, "'" ].join('')
//alert(command)
kernel.execute(command)
var command = ["notebookName = ",
               "'", window.document.body.dataset.notebookName, "'" ].join('')
//alert(command)
kernel.execute(command)
```

Then you can check the python variables notebookName and notebookPath

I am not sure of the result in case of url prefix , and how to handle the case when you have already changed current directory in the notebook

Comment: result doesn't contain full path to notebook file (when I execute from directory where notebook)

Comment: it's possible to add `notebook_full_path = os.path.abspath(notebookName)`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers don't get the proper full path. They either get it relative to the notebook working directory of the kernel or the Jupyter home directory.

**Here's how to get the full notebook path:**

First, use a JavaScript cell to grab the notebook filename, URL decode it and drop it into a Python variable:

```js
%%javascript
// Fetch and decode the notebook filename
var notebookFilename = decodeURIComponent(
    window.document.body.dataset.notebookName
);
// Drop the filename into a Python variable
Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute(
    `notebook_filename = "${notebookFilename}"`
);
```

Then in a second cell, convert that filename to an absolute path:

```py
import os
notebook_path = os.path.abspath(notebook_filename)
notebook_path
```

`notebook_path` will now be the full absolute path to the notebook.

*Tested on Chrome 77 on Ubuntu with jupyter-notebook 5.7.8*